# Insert String Into Particular Part of String

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that stores file  paths. Sometimes the documents get thrown into an "archive" sub folder. I've created a form that loads the record with the file name and file path. On the form I created a button that adds `\archive\` into the existing file path. The `\archive\` needs to be inserted after the last backslash found in the file path. Here's the function I've tried but I can't find the solution anywhere.

`Public Function insertArch (ByVal strPath As String)
       insertArchive = InStrRev(strPath, "\") + " archive\"
End Function`

I'm trying to find the first backslash from the end of the string, and then want to insert `archive\`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InStrRev` returns a character offset, not a string.

You can:

```
Public Function insertArchive(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long
    pos = InStrRev(strPath, "\")
    If (pos > 0) Then
        insertArchive = Left$(strPath, pos) & "archive\" & Mid$(strPath, pos + 1)
    Else
        insertArchive = strPath
    End If
End Function
```

For:

```
?insertArchive("C:\foo\bar\qux.dat")
C:\foo\bar\archive\qux.dat
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Appreciated.